# Tune for Travels in Parshas Maasei

Tags: torah-reading, music, parsha-torah-portion

In parshas Maasei, many have the minhag to do a tune for the travels at the beginning of the Parsha (Perek 33). Is anyone aware of a source or reason for this minhag?